# active and passive difference in these two examples? "This chair is too small to stand on." and "This chair is too small to be stood on."

Tags: active-vs-passive

"This chair is too small **to stand on.**"
"This chair is too small **to be stood on.**"
what's the difference? or I can use either one.

Comment: The first is more natural, and implies ' **for me** ' or '**for a person** to stand on'.

Comment: If you read books written before circa 1900, you'll encounter the passive infinitive form fairly often, e.g. *to be relied on* vs *to rely on*.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's no difference in meaning between *too ADJ to VERB* and *too ADJ to be VERBed*, but the latter form has been in [long-term decline](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=too%20tough%20to%20eat%2Ctoo%20tough%20to%20be%20eaten&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=20) over centuries...

[image]

---

*Syntactically*, it's irrelevant whether *ADJ to VERB / to be VERBed* is preceded by an "adverb of degree" such as ***too*** or not. It's essentially the same construction in...

> This product is...
> 1: *...ready to use*
> 2: *...easy to use*
> 3: *...ready to be used*
> 4: *...easy to be used*

...but the second pair are much less common than the first pair. #4 in particular has always been [extremely uncommon](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ready%20to%20use%2Cready%20to%20be%20used%2Ceasy%20to%20use%2Ceasy%20to%20be%20used&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) - in fact, many native would dismiss it out of hand as "non-idiomatic", even though there's no *syntactic* reason why it sounds so much more "awkward" than #3. My advice is to avoid *ADJ **to be** VERBed* in favour of *ADJ **to** VERB* wherever possible.